# What is the best way to compile nodejs on an arm board (cubieboard or raspberry pi)?

Tags: node.js, arm, raspberry-pi

After reading all kind of stuff (mostly out of date) I'm now lost on which is the best way to have nodejs running on [raspberry pi](http://www.raspberrypi.org/) or on [cubieboard](http://cubieboard.org/)?

I tried the following on both boards, and it works (since node.js 0.8.10).

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential libssl-dev
export NODE_VER=0.8.16
cd ~
curl http://nodejs.org/dist/v$NODE_VER/node-v$NODE_VER.tar.gz | tar xz
cd node-v$NODE_VER
./configure --shared-openssl --without-snapshot
time make CFLAGS+=-O2 CXXFLAGS+=-O2
sudo make install
```

But, since I'm completely noob when it comes to hardware related compilation, I don't even know if I'm right!

So my question(s) is(are) the following:

- is this procedure seems ok? no hidden problems?
- what shared-openssl and without-snapshot mean? (functionally speaking)
- what the **** these `CFLAGS` and `CXXFLAGS` are?

**UPDATE**

Thanks to the comments of you dear fellows, I dug into code.
So it seems that `shared-openssl` stands for :

> Link to a shared OpenSSl DLL instead of static linking ([here](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/configure#L64))

And `without-snapshot` stands for:

> Build without snapshotting V8 libraries. You might want to set this for cross-compiling. [Default: False]([here](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/configure#L38))

But I do not cross compile, so it seems useless, isn't it?

Then I tried to have a look for the `CFLAGS` and `CXXFLAGS` default values, but I found nothing relevant. Any idea?

Regards

Comment: Don't most Makefiles already default to `-O2`?

Comment: It's perfectly fine. `--shared-openssl` tells it to use the shared OpenSSL libraries instead of its built-in ones. The flags are extra flags passed to the compiler, and as Blender says, they probably already default to `-O2` and you probably don't need anything but `time make`.

Comment: The update from @finnw mess it all... No more mention of the usefulness of the ```without-snapshot```... re-edited

Comment: I did not change that part, only the title

Comment: Yes that's what's I'm saying...

Comment: But the title never referred to `without-snapshot`, and when a title contains phrases like *"what is the best..."* the question attracts close votes

Comment: Yes I know, what I was trying to say is that your edit reduces the scope of the original question. And the scope your edited title suggests is not the scope of my original question.

Comment: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/